# Using python filter with multiple functions and conditional operators

Tags: lambda, filter, python-3.6

I was interested in filtering a set of numbers through several functions with suitable 'and' and 'or' operators. For example, I wrote the following code for filtering all the prime numbers ending with seven:

```
is_prime = lambda x : all([x%j for j in range(2,x)])
ends_with_7 = lambda x : x % 10 == 7

primes_ending_with_7 = list(filter(is_prime and ends_with_7, range(1, 200)))
print(primes_ending_with_7)
```

It produced the following output, which was obviously wrong:

```
[7, 17, 27, 37, 47, 57, 67, 77, 87, 97, 107, 117, 127, 137, 147, 157, 167, 177, 187, 197]
```

It is possible for me to collapse the two lambdas into one as follows and get the desired result:

```
is_prime7 = lambda x : all([x%j for j in range(2,x)]) and x % 10 == 7
```

But, it stifles the purpose of keeping the **ends_with_7** as an independent function. Is there a way out to keep functions usable in their own right and still apply a filter by logically combining them?

Comment: Do you really want to use `filter` here? It's probably easier to grok if you don't but...

Comment: Try typing `is_prime and ends_with_7` in your interpreter and see what you get - that'll give you an idea of why trying it that way doesn't/won't work...

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're after here though really... does `primes_ending_with7 = [n for n in range(1, 200) if is_prime(n) and ends_with_7(n)]` work for you?

Comment: Or possibly... `[n for n in range(1, 200) if all(f(n) for f in (is_prime, ends_with_7))]` ?

Comment: Thanks @JonClements for the variety of solutions. But, I am interested to know if filter can be used to connect disparate functions or lambda expressions, while preserving the stand-alone utility of those functions/lambda expressions.

Comment: No it can't... it almost looks like you're trying to apply functional programming composition stuff here? What with the use of `lambda` instead of `def`s and the use of `filter`... this looks very much like an attempt to write Haskell in Python :)